# Docusign Ruby API - receiving 302 when try to do something

Tags: ruby, docusignapi

I am getting 302 when I try to do something with docusign-ruby-client.

```rb
envelope_args = {
  signer_email: 'email@email.com',
  signer_name: 'Name',
  cc_email: 'another@email.com',
  cc_name: 'Another name',
  template_id: 'template-id'
}

args = {
  client_id: 'my-client-id',
  impersonated_user_guid: 'my-impersonated-user-guid',
  base_path: 'account-d.docusign.com',
  envelope_args: envelope_args
}

envelope_args = args[:envelope_args]
configuration = DocuSign_eSign::Configuration.new
configuration.host = args[:base_path]

path = File.join(File.dirname(File.absolute_path(__FILE__)), 'private-key.txt')
private_key = File.read(path)

api_client = DocuSign_eSign::ApiClient.new configuration
api_client.set_oauth_base_path(args[:base_path])

token = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(args[:client_id], args[:impersonated_user_guid], private_key, 3600)

user_info = api_client.get_user_info(token.access_token)
template_api = DocuSign_eSign::TemplatesApi.new(api_client)
template_api.list_templates(user_info.accounts.first.account_id)
```

I created an JWT integration key, also authorized my user/ app and I see that I have an `user_info.accounts.first.account_id` when I execute `user_info = api_client.get_user_info(token.access_token)`.

When I try to execute any `api.list_something` I receive:

```
302
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://account-d.docusign.com/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Are you using base_path correctly? It doesn’t look like it. https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ruby-client/blob/master/lib/docusign_esign/configuration.rb#L163 It’s not the host name.

Comment: Hi @anothermh. You're write.

There are 2 hosts: DocuSign_eSign::Configuration.host and DocuSign_eSign::ApiClient.set_oauth_base_path

I was using the same path for both. 

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @anothermh. Try setting your api_client's base path:

```
    api_client.config.host = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi'
```

The above base path is for demo (the developer sandbox).

For production, you need to pull the base path out of the `get_user_info` response.